# How to save selenium session on whatsap

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have code "Auto Sender Notify", the problem however is that I need to scan a QR code every time.

Does somebody know methods to save cookies and add to code, so it will work together?

Many thanks 
​

```
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import socket
​
message_text='bla bla' # message you want to send
no_of_message= 1 # no. of time you want the message to be send
moblie_no_list=[1565626322] # list of phone number can be of any length
​
def element_presence(by,xpath,time):
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))
    WebDriverWait(driver, time).until(element_present)
​
def is_connected():
    try:
        # connect to the host -- tells us if the host is actually
        # reachable
        socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 80))
        return True
    except :
        is_connected()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://web.whatsapp.com")
sleep(10) #wait time to scan the code in second
​
def send_whatsapp_msg(phone_no,text):
    driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={}&source=&data=#".format(phone_no))
    try:
        driver.switch_to().accept()
    except Exception as e:
        pass
​
    try:
        element_presence(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]',30)
        txt_box=driver.find_element(By.XPATH , '//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]')
        global no_of_message
        for x in range(no_of_message):
            txt_box.send_keys(text)
            txt_box.send_keys("\n")
​
    except Exception as e:
        print("invailid phone no :"+str(phone_no))
for moblie_no in moblie_no_list:
    try:
        send_whatsapp_msg(moblie_no,message_text)
​
    except Exception as e:
        sleep(10)
        is_connected()
```

Answer (score 1):

save the cookies to file and read it later.

```
import json

def saveCookies(driver):
    cookies = driver.get_cookies()
    with open('cookies.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(cookies))

def setCookies(driver):
    try:
        with open('cookies.json', 'r') as f:
            for cookie in json.load(f):
                driver.add_cookie(cookie)
    except: pass
```

To use it

```
driver.get("http://web.whatsapp.com")
setCookies(driver)
# check if it asking for the code
try:
    if driver.find_element_by_???:
        sleep(10) #wait time to scan the code in second
except: pass # no input code needed, skip sleep
.....
.....
for moblie_no in moblie_no_list:
    ....
    ....

saveCookies(driver)
```

Comment: don't use bare exceptions